# How do I calculate with dates in my measure but hide them in my visual without ruining the calculated value?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

I have some sales data going back 4 years (monthly data, my date is the last day of the month, the sales values are monthly sums). I made a measure with sameperiodlastyear where I can compare the data to the previous year which I use in 2 other measure where I calculate differences (2022-2021, 2023-2022) that I have to use in my visual.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N45Cn.png)

How can I apply a date filter on my visual without ruining my calculated values?

If I apply my date filter on the visual level filter to remove 2021, my measured values go crazy...
I have Date table, I tried to calculate my sameperiodlastyear with it, but I didn't get back the right numbers in my sum

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.